# Color an individual bar in a vaadin basic bar chart

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I have a basic bar chart in my project

Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.BAR);

How could I get the 10th or 20th bar in my chart and set the color of that individual bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `DataSeries` you could set the color for a concrete `DataSeriesItem` via `DataSeriesItem.setColor()` method.

for example, starting from the Chart instance

```
DataSeries dataSeries = (DataSeries) chart.getConfiguration().getSeries().get(0); 
dataSeries.get(10).setColor(SolidColor.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have to customize elements in Vaadin I usually try one of the following:

- from java classes, isolate the component and use a setter method if existing
- do the changes from CSS, a starting point is [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Dynamically+injecting+CSS) or [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.css.html).
- do the changes from javascript, this is a good starting point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17394993/3993221)

My recommendation is in this order.

I hope it helps.